# serialize object with subitems c#

Tags: c#, serialization

var store = GetStore();
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = store.OpenFile(RootData, FileMode.Create))
{
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List));
serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, rootdatalist);
}

But this only serializes the rootdatalist, and not the subitems. The rootdatalist has a nodes List property, how do I serialize that, so that I get the list hierarchy serialized?

Since it's dbml generated objects the Nodes property of Root is

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Node> Nodes
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetTable<Node>();
    }
}
```

My Datacontext return is:

```
public List<Root> GetRootList(Guid userid)
{
   DataLoadOptions loadopts = new DataLoadOptions();
   loadopts.LoadWith<Root>(s => s.Nodes);
   this.DataContext.LoadOptions = loadopts;
   return this.DataContext.Root.Where(s => s.Nodes.Count(n => n.UserId == userid) > 0).ToList();
}
```

the Node entityset looks as follows in my dbml designer

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="Root_Node", Storage="_Nodes", ThisKey="Id", OtherKey="RootId")]
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=5, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
public EntitySet<Node> Nodes
{
    get
    {
        if ((this.serializing && (this._Nodes.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false)))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return this._Nodes;
    }
    set
    {
        this._Nodes.Assign(value);
    }
}
```

Also I have to have the `[Include]`tag above my properties or nothing will be loaded.
Edit::
To others wanting to serialize dbml classes [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wriju/linq-to-sql-enabling-dbml-file-for-wcf)

Comment: Is there any [DataMember] info above `Nodes`? And what is `Root` here? The fact that it exposes a `Table<T>` makes me think it is a `DataContext`, but a `DataContext` is not (AFAIK) intended to be part of the serializable model - it is more the manager than a domain object. (a regular relationship from a unidirectional dbml-generated type would be `EntitySet<T>`, not `Table<T>`)

Comment: It is definately part of a datacontext, but i thought that the object would be serializable when I added the unidirectional serialization according to the bottom link of my post. Unforunately it doesn't quite seem so. I'm not quite shure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @Jakob - exactly; the *data-context* isn't designed to be serializable. It is only your *domain entities* that become serializable. However; what is your goal here? I might have more than a few tricks up my sleeve... (I humbly submit that I'm *painfully* familiar with .NET serialization in multiple guises)

Comment: @Marc - I'm so glad that you say that. My goal is simply to have a method for serializing and deserializing a List<Root> object, and maintain the Root -> Nodes hierarchy. Since the Nodes property is a EntityRef in the return of data from my datacontext I do as specified in the edit of my main post

Comment: @Jakob - are there any attributes on the `Root` class or the `Nodes` property? And can you confirm: the `Nodes` property you have shown - is that really on `Root`? or is that on the data-context? `this.GetTable<...>()` **really** looks like data-context to me, but you say it is "the Nodes property of Root"...

Comment: It has dawned on me that I've forgotten to tell a central point I think. It is only the Nodes that don't get serialized. I have the Root entities serialized, but the Nodes property of Root has no items in it. I know from debugging that when I pass the list in to serialization there are items in the Nodes collection of the root entity object.

I have a dbml generated class called Root with a property of Nodes, I hope that answers your question. Please do take into account that I might be unwillingly misinforming you simply because I'm not sure of how to discriminate, I apologize for this.

Comment: @Jakob - and can you show the `Root.Nodes` property, including attributes? I don't think the one above is it; I think that is the data-context's `Nodes` property (i.e. all nodes in the database, rather than all nodes related to this root). [I'm off to bed, btw; so won't reply for a few hours]

Comment: @Marc - I Hope I've done what you've asked for. The code should be at the bottom of my main post. I've been having a look at 
http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2007/11/serializing-object-graphs-with-and.html which you are probably familiar with, and I'm struggling to grasp why it works, when what I have doesn't. The dbml has the datacontract and datamembers set up. It should be able to just serialize a List<Root> without any problems, not even having to specify known types. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Unrelated; LINQ improvement: `s.Nodes.Any(n => n.UserId == userid)`

Comment: I don't know why that isn't working. The main thing that occurs is that the `LoadWith` *hasn't*, and the data isn't loaded. If you deliberately force this (for example, for a `int i = 0; foreach(var root in rootdatalist) {i+=root.Nodes.Count;} Debug.WriteLine(i);`, which should force all the `Nodes` to load themselves), does it serialize *then*?

Comment: Goodmorning :) it runs the loop adding to the i value, but the nodes are not serialized.

Comment: I can tell from looking at the generated xml that the Nodes property isn't serialized at all. There's not even an empty Nodes property.

Comment: But the LoadWith - to my understanding should eliminate the lazy-load problem of serialization. What's more weird is that it's actually returned by a WCF service so It should already be serialized -right?

Comment: Are you shure that LoadWith doesn't load the data?

Comment: Hi @Jakob - sorry, catching up now. For info, I only get notified of messages if you use `@Marc` ;p

Comment: @Jakob - can you find out what `Nodes.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues` indicates? is it `true`? or `false`? Ditto `Nodes.IsDefered` ?

Comment: @Marc - I'll keep that in mind - I'm just very gratefull that you are still with me, I thought for a moment that I'd scared you away with dumb questions ;) The root objects that I pass on have _entitiesLoaded = true in the _Nodes Non Public member. How do I check for the other values?

Comment: @Jakob - hmmm. I'm struggling. I think I'm going to have to try to reproduce locally.

Comment: @Marc if you need any additional information or anything like that please let me know

Comment: @Jakob - is it just a standard foreign key ? anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: @Marc - Nothing out of the ordinary to my belief - it's a simple 1 -> many relationship

Comment: @Marc - have you had any luck reproducing the problem?

Comment: @Jakob - I tried, but it simply worked. Will try again tomorrow.

Comment: @Marc - I really appreciate your help. It's just a sample,can you perhaps send it to me so I can see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Marc - does it have anything to do with the Nodes in the Node also having a property called Root?

Comment: @Jakob - I honestly don't know. I'll try again with a basic example.

Comment: @Jakob - any thoughts on the additional investigations I provided? I still can't repro, but I'm intrigued where the difference is between my working example and your non-working one. I can't tell without more feedback from you.

Comment: @Marc - what does this tell you? If I simply store the List<Root> object from the server, for the rest of the application session (meaning until I close the app) I have a hierarchical tree. However, if I restart, only the Root objects and not the Root.Nodes objects are populated. So It resembles the serializing issue. Are the entities not detached correctly or something like that?

Comment: @Jakob - is "restart" involving deserialization? I would *expect* deserialized objects to be fully detached - i.e. no lazy / deferred loading.

Comment: @Marc - restart meaning - if I close and open the application again. No this is not with any serialization, I wanted to explore this weird phenomenon more, since I can trace no difference in your working and my non-working, so I tried detaching the list and then just saving as an object, instead of serializing, to see what the result would be, but that seemed not to work either, although when i debug the entitystate is detached. I must have some vital flaw in my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you include any more information about the contract types? I would *expect*, for example, that `Root` is marked as a data-contract, with the member as a data-member, for example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Root {
    [DataMember]
    public List<SubItem> Nodes {get;private set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class SubItem {
    [DataMember]
    public int Foo {get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}
```

That should then work. If not, it would really help to see your types (or a cut-down version of them, that illustrates the problem).

Answer (score 7):

The `DataContractSerializer` needs to know about *all* of the types in your object graph.

Use the [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344259.aspx) that lets you specify those as well as the root type:

```
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Root>), listOfOtherTypes);
```

Comment: will this also work if the List<Node> is actually EntityRef<Node> in the Root class?

Comment: @Jakob - It should, so long as you tell the serializer about the type. See the answer from Marc as well, as you do need to specify your `DataContract`s and `DataMember`s correctly too.

Comment: since this is generated, the contracts should be correct already. And in *most* scenarios it is **not** necessary to supply an additional data to the ctor. In particular, inheritance can be dealt with via `[KnownType]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

OK; I've had another go at reproducing this, using the `Person` / `PersonPhone` tables (in the `Person` schema) from a fresh AdventureWorks2008R2 install.

I have the data-context set to "Unidirectional" serialization, with standard LINQ-to-SQL bindings etc (no customisations).

To compare to your scenario, a `Person` can have `PersonPhone`s, and we are interested in a `List<Person>`. I've looked at 3 scenarios, each looking at the full set of data:

1. serializing a vanilla set of `Person` records
2. the same as 1, but using `LoadWith` to get the phone records
3. the same as 1, but manually iterating the data (note: this may cause N+1 issues)

Here is the results; as you can see, 1 fails in the way you describe, but 2 & 3 work fine, with the distinction that 3 does **significantly** more TSQL work.

So *without further details* (ideally a fully reproducible example), it is *very* hard to investigate further...

Results:

```
Default
=======
Bytes: 20219898
Original person count: 19972
Original phone count: 0
Deser person count: 19972
Deser phone count: 0
Log: 1140

LoadWith
========
Bytes: 24767996
Original person count: 19972
Original phone count: 19972
Deser person count: 19972
Deser phone count: 19972
Log: 2517

Enumerated
==========
Bytes: 24767996
Original person count: 19972
Original phone count: 19972
Deser person count: 19972
Deser phone count: 19972
Log: 6322697
```

Test rig:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(var dc = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        { // 1: vanilla
            dc.Log = new StringWriter();
            RoundtripAndCount("Default", dc.Persons);
            Console.WriteLine("Log: " + dc.Log.ToString().Length);
        }
        using (var dc = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        { // 2: LoadWith
            dc.Log = new StringWriter();
            var opt = new DataLoadOptions();
            opt.LoadWith<Person>(p => p.PersonPhones);
            dc.LoadOptions = opt;
            RoundtripAndCount("LoadWith", dc.Persons);
            Console.WriteLine("Log: " + dc.Log.ToString().Length);
        }
        using (var dc = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        { // 3: iterate manually
            dc.Log = new StringWriter();
            // manually iterate the data (LINQ-to-Objects)
            GC.KeepAlive(dc.Persons.AsEnumerable().Sum(p=>p.PersonPhones.Count())); // just an opaque method
            RoundtripAndCount("Enumerated", dc.Persons);
            Console.WriteLine("Log: " + dc.Log.ToString().Length);
        }
    }

    static void RoundtripAndCount(string caption, IEnumerable<Person> people)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(caption);
        Console.WriteLine(new string('=', caption.Length));
        List<Person> list = people.ToList(), clone;
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (List<Person>));
            ser.WriteObject(ms, list);
            ms.Position = 0;
            clone = (List<Person>) ser.ReadObject(ms);
            Console.WriteLine("Bytes: " + ms.Length);
        }
        Func<Person, int> phoneCount = p => p.PersonPhones.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues ? p.PersonPhones.Count() : 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Original person count: " + people.Count());
        Console.WriteLine("Original phone count: " + people.Sum(phoneCount));

        Console.WriteLine("Deser person count: " + clone.Count());
        Console.WriteLine("Deser phone count: " + clone.Sum(phoneCount));

    }
}
```

As a side-note, I *could* tweak protobuf-net to convince L2S into giving it the data (where `DataContractSerializer` decides to ignore it), but this reproduces scenario 3 with a huge N+1 cost. Consequently, I am not planning to pursue that...

Comment: @Marc - would you like to have a shared view with ms teamviewer, or something like that?

Comment: @Marc - are there any [include] tags in the metadata? I have to have those in my project, or nothing loads

Comment: @Jakob - I'll check. The sample is on my other machine, unfortunately.

Comment: @Marc - would you be interested in my previous preposal to have an overview of the code via teamviewer?

Comment: @Marc - can I send you an email with a teamviewer invite?

Comment: @Jakob - I simply can't at the minute; I'm happy to offer my thoughts, and I've tried to reproduce a few times (see below), but I'm going to be busy at least until the end of the week...

Comment: @Marc - okay :) I'm perfectly understanding of that, I didn't mean to steal your time, I only thought it would be simpler that way, and I really appreciate your participation in this thread.

Comment: @Marc - I'm still struggling to see what I'm doing wrong, so if at any point you have 5 minutes in which I can show you my code via teamviewer, please let me know, I'll try to keeep resolving this very trobulesome issue, and if you're not up for it for any reason, it's perfectly Ok too. thanks